# Как стилизовать input type = "password"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Мне нужно стилизовать input вот таким образом http://prntscr.com/r46e70   Как можно это сделать БЕЗ замены типа инпута на text? Спасибо!!!

Comment: А сейчас какой тип у `input` стоит у Вас?

Comment: input type="password"

Comment: Вам нужны просто звёздочки вместо точек, или именно такие?

Comment: именно такие...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let $input = $('input[type="password"]'),
  $wrapperMask = $('.wrapper-mask');

$input.on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 8) {
    $('.wrapper-mask').find('span').last().remove();
  } else {
    if ($('.wrapper-mask').find('span').length > 7) return;
    $wrapperMask.append('<span class="star"></span>');
  }
})
```

```css
input[type="password"]{color:#fff;height:30px;width:250px}
.wrapper{display:flex;align-items:center;max-width:250px;overflow:hidden}
.wrapper-mask{position: absolute;padding:0 5px}
.star{display:inline-block;background-image:url('https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/3d-gold-star-png-11552726957tpyco0iryc.png');background-size:contain;width:30px;height:30px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="wrapper">
  <span class="wrapper-mask"></span>
  <input type="password"/>
</span>
```

Comment: Ну тогда уж проще использовать unicode, если брать именно картинку )))